# Can I get help on an issue where unexpected/illegible characters render in Safari on some HTML pages?

Tags: macos, vpn, ventura, encoding, html

I am faced with a strange problem: On some websites, I have illegible characters and if I copy/paste the text into Google Translate or an editor like vim, the text appears normally in English.

Here an example on the page: ["The Alternate View" columns of John G. Cramer](https://www.npl.washington.edu/av/altvw206.html)

This is what I am seeing below:

[image: Illegible characters]

If I copy/paste the first paragraph into an editor, then I get :

> If you could halt the expansion of the universe and then travel
> outward in a straight line, would you eventually come back to the
> place where you started?  In other words, are all straight-line paths
> in the universe closed circles?  Or as Euclid would have put it, if
> you project two precisely parallel light beams out into empty space,
> do they ever cross?  A recent analysis of the angular structure and
> lensing of the cosmic microwave background radiation, as measured by
> the European Space Agency's Planck Mission, suggests that the answer
> to these questions is "Yes".  We will start by considering the
> curvature of space as represented in general relativity (GR).

I don't understand where this issue could come from. Even by trying with a different VPN, the issue remains.

I have also these same unrecognizable characters that represent normal text content on some gmail emails.

Is there a way to fix/troubleshoot this on macOS?

Comment: That is an ancient (in tech, anyway) website. I doubt it conforms to any modern standard like HTML 5.  What language/locale do you have your browser configured for?

Comment: Is the text  in english on your computer :  https://www.npl.washington.edu/av/altvw206.html ? Moreover, I have : `defaults read .GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages
(
    "fr-FR"
)` 

What do you think about this ? Some mails on gmail occurs with the same illisible characters, so should I conclude this comes from my macOS Ventura ?

Comment: It’s perfectly legibile for me (using US_English).  Given the vintage of the website and the language differences, it is definitely possible this is the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a corrupted font cache.

There are many way to clear the font cache: one of the easiest is to restart in Safe Boot mode (hold down SHIFT at startup); and then restart normally.